# Issue with Dreamweaver installation

Tags: adobe, dreamweaver

Hi my question is : I get Dreamweaver v 16 setup file form a website then open it and then asks me to choose a directory for extracting some files then i set path and click next and a few minutes later extracting finish without any error. But problem is here that files doesn't extract completely. i see just payloads folder in extracted path.

I tried this solutions :

1. rebooting
2. installing new windows ( windows 10 and 7 )  (my first time in
   windows 8.1)
3. trying other setup file from various sources(websites)

:(  same thing happen

[image: root folder]

[image: this is payloads folder]

Comment: this isn't a good place to ask for help with pirated software. also you shouldn't ever install something you "found on a website" you probably have malware/viruses now.  good work.